# Изменение объекта со специфичностью из css в js

Tags: javascript, css

Делаю поддержку тем с подгрузкой из json файла.
Есть у меня отрывок кода: `button:active{ background-color: #1b91ff;}`
Как реализовать смену фона у активной кнопки через js?

Comment: опишите поподробнее, почему нужен именно js, в какой момент или в следствие чего Вы хотите применять этот стиль возможно не лишним будет дополнить код HTML разметкой.

Comment: А чем вас это решение не устраивает? Или речь идёт про `:focus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда этим не занимался, но вам кажется нужен метод [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). В примере показано как с ним работать, но вот нужный индекс у `styleSheets` я взял простым перебором. Подозреваю, что не всегда это число бывает таким "приятным", потому вам ещё нужен будет метод определения этого индекса, которого я пока что не знаю

```js
document.styleSheets[1].insertRule('button.two:active {background-color: red;}', 0);
```

```css
button:active {
  background-color: #1b91ff;
}
```

```html
<button> One </button>
<button class='two'> Two </button>
<button> Three </button>
```

Comment: Да уж, способ приятный, но может что то на сайте мозиллы найду)

Comment: Ничего не нашёл, и перебирал уже много чего

Comment: @Linux_tester Ну проблема в том, что JS впринципе не имеет прямого доступа к псевдо, точно так же как и инлайн стили в HTML. Потому кроме извращений вы вряд ли что-то ещё найдёте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то пожалуйста, отметье его как принятый :)

Comment: Конечно приму, это очень удобно, только к сожалению не воспользовался этим